# Reverse DataFrame column order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reverse

I want to simply reverse the column order of a given DataFrame.

My DataFrame:

```
data = {'year': [2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012],
    'team': ['Bears', 'Bears', 'Bears', 'Packers', 'Packers', 'Lions', 'Lions', 'Lions'],
    'wins': [11, 8, 10, 15, 11, 6, 10, 4],
    'losses': [5, 8, 6, 1, 5, 10, 6, 12]}
football = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['year', 'team', 'wins', 'losses'])
```

Actual output:

```
   year     team  wins  losses
0  2010    Bears    11       5
1  2011    Bears     8       8
2  2012    Bears    10       6
3  2011  Packers    15       1
4  2012  Packers    11       5
5  2010    Lions     6      10
6  2011    Lions    10       6
7  2012    Lions     4      12
```

I thought this would work but it reverses the row order not column order:

```
football[::-1]
```

I also tried:

```
football.columns = football.columns[::-1]
```

but that reversed the column labels and not the entire column itself.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A solution close to what you have already tried is to use:

```
>>> football[football.columns[::-1]]
   losses  wins     team  year
0       5    11    Bears  2010
1       8     8    Bears  2011
2       6    10    Bears  2012
3       1    15  Packers  2011
4       5    11  Packers  2012
5      10     6    Lions  2010
6       6    10    Lions  2011
7      12     4    Lions  2012
```

`football.columns[::-1]` reverses the order of the DataFrame's sequence of columns, and `football[...]` reindexes the DataFrame using this new sequence.

A more succinct way to achieve the same thing is with the `iloc` indexer:

```
football.iloc[:, ::-1]
```

The first `:` means "take all rows", the `::-1` means step backwards through the columns.

The `loc` indexer mentioned in @PietroBattiston's answer works in the same way.

Comment: To put it more verbosely: `football[reversed(football.columns)]`

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

Close to [EdChum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817752/2858145)... but faster:

```
In [3]: %timeit football.ix[::,::-1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 255 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit football.ix[::,football.columns[::-1]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 491 µs per loop
```

Also notice one colon is redundant:

```
In [5]: all(football.ix[:,::-1] == football.ix[::,::-1])
Out[5]: True
```

**EDIT:** a further (minimal) improvement is brought by using `.loc` rather than `.ix`, as in `football.loc[:,::-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: As of Pandas v0.20, `.ix` [indexer is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix) in favour of `.iloc` / `.loc`.

You can use fancy indexing `.ix`, pass the columns and then reverse the list to change the order:

```
In [27]:

football.ix[::,football.columns[::-1]]
Out[27]:
   losses  wins     team  year
0       5    11    Bears  2010
1       8     8    Bears  2011
2       6    10    Bears  2012
3       1    15  Packers  2011
4       5    11  Packers  2012
5      10     6    Lions  2010
6       6    10    Lions  2011
7      12     4    Lions  2012
```

**timings**

```
In [32]:

%timeit football[football.columns[::-1]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 421 µs per loop
In [33]:

%timeit football.ix[::,football.columns[::-1]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 403 µs per loop
```

fancy indexing is marginally faster in this case