# How can you reverse row order in a bokeh datatabe (Python)?

Tags: python, dataframe, datatable, bokeh

I am building a web application and I am showing a dataframe there using the DataTable function from bokeh. I am trying to have it that the last row is displayed first and vice versa (reversing the row order). I can do this to the dataframe using the df.iloc[::1] function, but when converting to a datatable, the rows aren't reversed like I want them to be. Any help?

The code (example):

```
    df = pd.read_csv(myfile.csv)
    df = df.iloc[::1]
    Columns = [TableColumn(field=Ci, title=Ci) for Ci in df.columns]
    table = DataTable(columns=Columns, source=ColumnDataSource(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

You can revers the `Columns` variable, it is of type `list`.

```
table = DataTable(columns=Columns[::-1], source=ColumnDataSource(df))
```

**Longer answer**

Your implementation has one mistake which is not connected to the bokeh library.
This line *doesn't* revers the order of your Dataframe. Please try it out yourself.

```
df = df.iloc[::1]
```

You should solve the problem at this point. One of [many options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817718/reverse-dataframe-column-order) is this.

```
df = df[reversed(df.columns)]
```

This also works if you want to define your own order.

```
df = df[['c', 'b', 'a']]
```