# bug in reversing columns order of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have been trying to reverse the order of the columns I have in my dataframe but all the solutions I tried are not working for some reason.
Not sure what is the bug here, I'm pretty inexperienced with python, can someone tell me where I am going wrong with this?

I referred to this [Reverse DataFrame column order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817718/reverse-dataframe-column-order)

And these are the options I have tried:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
df3 = pd.read_csv(cwd + "/filepathA/filetoReaddata.csv", sep=" ", header =  None)

df3.columns = ["x_coord", "y_coord"]

#(option 1) df3.iloc[:, ::-1]
#(option 2) reversed(df3.columns)
#(option 3) df3.columns[::-1]
df3.head()
```

And they all return me the same dataframe with no changes made to the order. I.E it's the same as when I first read it in.

This is what my dataframe looks like so I want it to be `y_coord x_coord` instead, with the values swapped as well.

```
    x_coord         y_coord
0   0.000000        1.000000
1   38816.039612    34379.960205
2   38806.429627    34385.380188
3   38813.329590    34379.880188
4   38807.119629    34379.730164
```

Any help is appreciated thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
df = df.reindex(df.columns[::-1], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can try this,

```
df[df.columns[::-1]] = df[df.columns]
```

---

```
        x_coord       y_coord
0      1.000000      0.000000
1  34379.960205  38816.039612
2  34385.380188  38806.429627
3  34379.880188  38813.329590
4  34379.730164  38807.119629
```